# Same query, different DB's, same DB structure, same DB server, different execution plans

Tags: sql, sql-server

This one has me beat!

One of our clients has a single SQL Server instance with 2 DB's, one test and one production. Both DB's are identical, table structure, indexes etc. When a certain query (structure below) is run on the test DB, rows are returned within 30 sec. On the production DB, rows take 1.5 hours to return!! Activity Monitor shows the query running with no wait type. All statistics are up to date. When execution plans are compared, the main difference is a nested (prod) vs hash join (test). We can add an index on the production DB to improve the performance, receiving around the same execution time as the test server, but remembering that the test server doesn't need this additional index!

Unfortunately the client is not technical hence use of views joining to views (cringe). The issue itself is resolved in terms of performance (by adding the additional index on the production DB). But we still cannot work out why the test DB performs find without the additional index.

Can anyone shed some light? We're stumped!

query structure:

```
SELECT field1,
       field2,
       field3,
       DATEDIFF(mi, field5, field5) as 'Time'
  FROM MainView t
  JOIN SecondaryView i ON t.NonIndexedColumn = i.NonIndexedColumn
 WHERE date >= '2010/07/05'
   AND date < '2011/09/27'
   AND anotherDate IS NULL
   AND Code LIKE 'Abc%'
   AND Desc LIKE('%ABC%')
```

Comment: What about perfmon stats while the query is running?

Comment: How about data amount?? How much data is there in your TEST environment?? If you have only 5-10% of the data of production, of course execution will be significantly different ...

Comment: same row count, same data extracted from same source system :(

Comment: You say it's the same DB Server - but how identical are they? Are they identical boxes from the same supplier, same I/O susbsystem, memory, processors etc, running same O/S, Same edition of SQL Server, same service packs, etc. Even trivial sounding differences may be enough of a difference for SQL Server to do something stupid.

Comment: Identical as in the 2 DBs are on the same server so 1 server, 1 db server, 2 dbs

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing both execution plans and some to and fro Q & A. I assume cardinality estimates are different in some part of the plan so it would be a question of identifying which part and then identifying the reason.

Answer (score -1):

It could be because of different data distribution on a disk or "table fragmentation".
If data was imported, for example, using

```
INSERT INTO test.table
SELECT * FROM prod.table
```

statements, then data in the test database doesn't have as much spaces as production. But this depends on how data is being treated in the production.

Check [sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188917.aspx) function

Comment: fragmentation does not affect choice of execution plan.